# I want to groupby, and then, create a new column which takes a value from a different column if a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe. I want to create a new column `col2` which takes a value from the column `value` after groupby ID, if the value from `col1` is BX.

and another new column `col3` which takes the value from `value` if the value from `col1 is AX.

```
ID value col1
A    1    BX
A    2    AX
B    3    BX
B    4    AX
C    5    BX
C    6    AX
```

desired df

```
ID value col1  col2 col3
A    1    BX    1    2
A    2    AX    1    2
B    3    AX    4    3    
B    4    BX    4    3 
C    5    BX    5    6
C    6    AX    5    6
```

Comment: Can there be multiple values for BX or AX in a group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform two merges: one where `col1 = 'BX'` and one where `col1 = 'AX'`.

```
df = df.merge(df.loc[df['col1'] == 'BX', ['ID', 'value']].rename({'value': 'col2'}, axis=1), on='ID')
df = df.merge(df.loc[df['col1'] == 'AX', ['ID', 'value']].rename({'value': 'col3'}, axis=1), on='ID')
```

Output:

```
  ID  value col1  col2  col3
0  A      1   BX     1     2
1  A      2   AX     1     2
2  B      3   BX     3     4
3  B      4   AX     3     4
4  C      5   BX     5     6
5  C      6   AX     5     6
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there can only be one value for `ax` and `bx` try using `pivot` and `merge`. `Pivot` will take all the values in `col1` and create new columns for each unique value. When merged, all the unique values in `col1` will be added as a new column in `new_df`

```
p = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='col1', values='value')
new_df = df.merge(p, left_on='ID', right_index=True, how='left')

  ID  value col1  AX  BX
0  A      1   BX   2   1
1  A      2   AX   2   1
2  B      3   BX   4   3
3  B      4   AX   4   3
4  C      5   BX   6   5
5  C      6   AX   6   5
```